# How to make a CSS :hover persistent after hover?

Tags: html, css

I have created a navigation bar with a `:hover` effect and I'd like to know how to make that effect persistent, even after the cursor is removed from the area. The effect is a background color under the given word. For example, when Home is selected I'd like for that effect to stay on the element until another element (for example, Register) is clicked.

```css
.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
    padding: 17px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: honeydew;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul class='navbar'>
            <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#download'>Download</a></li>
            <li><a href='#register'>Register</a></li>
            <li><a href='#contact'>Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href='#FAQ'>FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

The desired effect can be achieved with just CSS but it's tricky and the only way I know of would cause your links to become non-functional (since it requires replacing your links with `<input type="radio">`). So overall, I would recommend to use JavaScript for this.

The JavaScript way would be, using jQuery, to add a class when the `mouseover` event is triggered and to remove it from all other elements on another desired event getting triggered.

Example: (I have replaced the `:hover` pseudoselector with a `.hover` class selector and added the jQuery library and required code.)

jQuery is not required to achieve this effect, you can do this just fine with vanilla JavaScript.

```js
$(".navbar a").on("mouseover", function () {
    $(".navbar a").removeClass("hover");
    $(this).addClass("hover");
});
```

```css
.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
    padding: 17px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}

.navbar a.hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: honeydew;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul class='navbar'>
            <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#download'>Download</a></li>
            <li><a href='#register'>Register</a></li>
            <li><a href='#contact'>Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href='#FAQ'>FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: i just tried this but seems don't work